# Length of URL Language Code in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I need to change the content language URL Code for the french part of a Website to "costumes" (Found in the language manager under "content"). However the field stops after 7 letters, so that the last "s" is cut of.
I want to change that because the website-languages where set up as categories before, so that the french part is indexed by Google and others like that. Is there a way to allow 8 letters in this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to change `maxlength` variable from file: `/administrator/components/com_languages/models/forms/language.xml`

```
        <field name="lang_code" type="text"
            description="COM_LANGUAGES_FIELD_LANG_TAG_DESC"
            label="COM_LANGUAGES_FIELD_LANG_TAG_LABEL"
            maxlength="7"
            required="true"
            size="10"
        />    

            <field name="sef" type="text"
                description="COM_LANGUAGES_FIELD_LANG_CODE_DESC"
                label="COM_LANGUAGES_FIELD_LANG_CODE_LABEL"
                maxlength="7"
                required="true"
                size="10"
        />
```

This is a core change and every time you upgrade your joomla installation you have to check if it is getting overridden. If you want to create an override, you will need a [3rd party plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/templating/15611).

Good Luck!